# How do i access the elements on the page that appears after successful login using scraping?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation

How do i access the elements of the page that appears after successful login 
Our college has a website that displays the attendance of the students after they login , i am using .send_keys function to send the login information, i can see the successful login window too !..........how do i proceed further to extract the attendance data ?
After successful login ,if i print driver.current_url and click on that url it redirects me to the login page again, how do i deal with this?

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import urllib.request
import requests
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\ADITYA\\chromedriver")
driver.get("https://14.139.110.183/geca/") 
time.sleep(1)
username = driver.find_element_by_id("txt_username")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("txt_password")
captcha_input = input()
captcha = driver.find_element_by_id("txtCapcha")

#We have to fill up the captcha on our site . 
#This step is currently done manually, We plan to automate captcha detection using machine Learning.

username.send_keys("myusername")
password.send_keys("mypassword")
captcha.send_keys(captcha_input)
login_attempt = driver.find_element_by_id("btnSubmit")
login_attempt.click()
time.sleep(5)

print(driver.current_url)
#print(browser.cuurent_url)
uurl = driver.current_url
driver.get(uurl)
```

I am able to successfully login , but to extract the further data, what URL should i use to extract the elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [driver.get()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get) URL only once to open the initial page of your application. The URL will be automatically changing as you will be interacting with your application (clicking [buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button) and [links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks), submitting [forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), etc.)

You can get the website data by:

1. Using [driver.find_element()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element) function to locate the element at the page
2. Using [element.get_attribute()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) to get [HTML attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) values and [element.text](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) to get the text value of the given element.

One more important hint - consider using [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead of time.sleep, this will make your test faster and more reliable. Check out [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) article for more information.